# Watir won't choose the files I need to upload

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload, watir, directory, watir-webdriver

Part of my watir script tests an upload form. I can get the upload box to open, but it won't navigate to the folder and choose the file I want. Instead, the script will crash and give this error:
No such file or directory - /Users/Abdulla/Documents/Ads/1.jpg (Errno::ENOENT)

Here's my code, I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. This is using chromewatir on a mac btw.

```
browser.file_field(:name, "u").click
browser.file_field(:name, "u").set("/Users/Abdulla/Documents/Ads/1.jpg")
```

Is the path name supposed to start with /Users? Or should it be /Documents? Because when it clicks choose file on the site it opens right in the Documents folder.

Comment: Chromewatir?!?! This one? https://rubygems.org/gems/chromewatir

Comment: Not sure how many Chromewatir folks hang out here, there's no tag for it, so this might not be the best venue for an answer if it is something very specific to chromewatir.  I'm also not sure how active that project is, especially now that we have the Watir-Webdriver stuff, which supports IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: Chromewatir is dead-dead, I do not think you can even install it any more.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would recommend switching to Watir-Webdriver to drive chrome.  As indicated in the comments, the chrome-watir project is pretty much dead at this point

2) check that the file exists.

3) check that the user which watir (or watir-webdriver) is running under has access to that file. or consider putting the file in a more public directory (in terms of permissions to the directory)

4) I can't say for sure on mac, but on a PC, the chrome upload file selector remembers the last directory used to upload files and opens to the same place (presumably as a convenience to the user), however specifying the full file path to the file should not be a problem.  You could always try doing that manually and see if it works or not if you need to be sure.

5) I'm not sure we can tell you what the correct path is, after all it's your system, your users, and your file that are involved, you'd know far more about what you are doing in that respect than any of us would.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `/Users/Abdulla/Documents/Ads/1.jpg` file does not exist, as the error message says.

Comment: If it's on unix/linux, maybe the process running the test doesn't have permission to the folder or file. Seems like a unix/linux path to me.

Comment: Good point Dave, I'd suggest you provide it as a potential answer.  the use of forward-slashes does tend to tell me this isn't likely to be windows unless the user is easily confused between / and \

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you use 'watir-webdriver'.

I think you don't need click the file field, only need to set the file path.

```
local_file = "/Users/Abdulla/Documents/Ads/1.jpg"
puts (File.exists? local_file)
browser.file_field(:id => 'upComponent').set  local_file
```